# How can I generate instances of a class with inter-dependent attributes?

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

Assume this simple case:  (reposted and lightly edited from [the Hypothesis mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/hypothesis-users/c/munEwoJDUCY/m/7BWnti9OAwAJ))

```py
@dataclass
class A:
   names: list[str]
   ages: dict[str, float]
```

How could I write a strategy which generates objects of type A but with the restriction that the keys in the ages dict are taken from the list names (which are, in turn, randomly generated)?

Comment: `dataclass` doesn't seem like a good fit.  Is the intent that both of those containers are mutable, and that changes in one should be reflected in the other?  Are they both auto-generated when an `A` is constructed and then frozen at that point?  Is one of them the source of truth and the other derived from it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to generate inter-dependent data, of which I'd usually recommend [reaching for `@st.composite` strategies](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#composite-strategies) - the imperative approach is a bit more verbose, but easy to read and works even for really complicated situations.  Here:

```
@st.composite
def a_instances(draw):
    ages = draw(st.dictionaries(st.text(), st.floats()))
    names = list(ages)  # could add elements, shuffle, etc here too.
    return A(names=names, ages=ages)
```

---

Or we could exploit the simplicity of the `A` class, and use a simpler but harder-to-extend strategy like:

```
a_instances = st.dictionaries(st.text(), st.floats()).map(
    lambda ages: A(names=list(ages), ages=ages
)
```

As Samwise notes though, this is a pretty strange example and I'd personally try tidying up the code a bit then using `@st.composite`.